# Can I resize a bezier path like a regular view in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, vector

I'm trying to resize a bezier drawn circle in an app I am making for iPad. The only way I know of so far is to use `CATransform3DMakeScale`. But, is there a way in which I can simply specify a height or width for the circle's shape layer and it will resize it to fit my specifications. Simply because I think this will be a lot more easy and consistent than using a scale all the time.

Comment: Why don't you just create the circle at the right size in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, you want the circle to fit the UIView it's drawn in?
If you are creating your circle as a subclass of UIView, you can do this by using methods `setNeedsDisplay` and `drawRect`.

```
class CircleView: UIView {
    let radius: CGFloat = min(self.frame.width, self.frame.height) / 2 {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // draw your UIBezierPath here
    }
}
```

First you get the radius for your circle from views width or height, depending on which one is smaller. Then you call `setNeedsDisplay()` which will do what's inside `drawRect`.

For more information, please take a look at class references for both classes:

[UIView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/)

[UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBezierPath_class/index.html)